# Apache 2.4 + Glassfish Server 2.1 post too large error

Tags: java, apache, glassfish

I'm using `Apache 2.4` with `Glassfish 2.1` and I keep getting this error with large posts:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Post too large

I've already tried to change the property maxPostSize of the Glassfish http-listener to a lot of values (and even 0, to accept everything) but nothing seems to work.

Do you guys know of any other thing that might be an issue here?

PS: The post has only 4MB. I think that anything bigger than 2Mb is being rejected.

**EDIT**: If I take the Apache out of the way, the request works fine. So it isn't a Glassfish bug but something in the communication of Apache-Glassfish. No idea what though.

**EDIT 2**: As the error was only happening in a specific service, I opened a direct glassfish port only to that end. That "solved" the problem.

Comment: Can you put the Httpd.conf apache configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

**Configure post request max size in Glassfish server**

Under http-service element in 
`${glassfish.home}/domains/domain/config/domain.xml`,
you can try adding the following property (or use admin-gui):

```
<property name="maxPostSize" value="...."/>
```

**Configure request size in Apache**

This directive is set to unlimited by default. If you are allowing file uploads of no larger than 1MB, you could set this setting to something like:

```
LimitRequestBody 1048576
```

You can change request size from `extra/httpd-default.conf` (uncomment what you want to configure)

```
#LimitRequestLine: Limit on bytes in Request-Line (Method+URI+HTTP-version).
#Maximum value set by DEFAULT_LIMIT_REQUEST_LINE in httpd.h to 8190KB
#Limit HTTP request size in bytes
#LimitRequestLine 8190

#LimitRequestFieldsize: Limit on bytes in any one header field.
#Maximum value set by DEFAULT_LIMIT_REQUEST_FIELDSIZE in httpd.h to 8190KB
#Limit length must be less than LimitRequestLine.
#LimitRequestFieldsize 8190

#LimitRequestBody: Limit on bytes in Request-Line.
#LimitRequestBody 8190
#LimitRequestFields: Limit on number of request header fields.

#LimitRequestFields 100
```

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if this was an official bug for Glassfish 2.1. If the above solution doesn't work for you, try to install the latest Glassfish version (Current version is [Glassfish 4.1](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html)).

Comment: @ViniciusSPaiva What did you put in the `value` attritube of the above property?

Comment: Tried to put 41943040 (40MB) and 0 (no limit)

Comment: @ViniciusSPaiva Try to install newest Glassfish version. See EDIT.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The problem is that is not easy to change our version right now. I was hoping to fix this on 2.1 =(. It appears to be something blocking anything I put on this property, it's keeping the default: 2MB.

Comment: I added an edit. This property works fine if I take out Apache. Doesn't do anything if Apache is back on.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help! But nothing works =(. This seems to be such an easy problem, and install the latest version is not an option right now (probably will have to change a lot of stuff).